# Конструктор для точки с заранее неизвестным количеством координат

Tags: c#

Как сделать конструктор `Object` и метод `FormList` динамичными, чтобы они работали не с тремя координатами (x, y, z) пункта, а с N?

```
internal class Object
{   
    private double X, Y, Z;

    public Object(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public static Object FromList(List<double> l)
    {
        if (l.Count != 3)
            throw new ArgumentException();
       return new Object(l[0], l[1], l[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Передавайте массив координат: `public Object(double[] coors)`. `Object`, кстати, - не лучшее название на класса.

Comment: Извините, не совсем понятно. а название класса это просто пример, согласна, что не совсем коректное.

Comment: конструктор должен остаться "пустым"?

Comment: DreamChild уже расписал в ответе. Полный пример в моём варианте выглядит [как-то так](https://goo.gl/RFq2fN).

Comment: а если подразумевается наличие только трех координат, то варианта с параметрами `double? y = null` не достаточно будет?

Comment: в смысле может ли N быть больше 3 ?

Comment: Если у вас N измерений и вы хотите по каждому хранить значение, то вам отлично подойдет массив double[]

Comment: Так и использовать `List<double>`.

Answer (score 7):

Можно использовать массив, а ещё лучше - массив с модификатором `params`. Это ключевое слово позволяет передавать произвольное количество параметров в метод, которые по сути являются массивом. Пример:

```
class Object 
{
    public Object(params double[] args)
    {
       X = args[0];
       Y = args[1];
       Z = args[2];
       // ...
    }
}

var obj = new Object(x, y, z, a, b);
```

Правда тут возникает проблема, заключающаяся в том, что вы никак не контролируете передаваемый массив и его длину, из-за чего может возникнуть `IndexOutOfRangeException`, но решить это можно например так:

```
class Object 
{
    public Object(params double[] args)
    {
       _data = args;
    }

    private readonly double[] _data;

    public double X 
    {
        get 
        {
            if(_data != null && _data.Length >= 1)
                return _data[0];
            throw SomeException(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Если вариант с выбросом исключения не устраивает, можно вместо него возвращать какое-то значение по умолчанию или изменить тип `X` на `double?` и возвращать в таких случаях null (не очень элегантный вариант впрочем).

При этом если у вас заранее не известно количество координат, то здесь вообще возникает вопрос целесообразности введения свойств/полей X, Y и Z